# Disable Java updater in registry

Tags: windows-7, java, windows-registry

Java updater ask for downloading new updates. How to disable on many computers in domain this feature? It is this checkbox:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/ut7W34C.png?1]

But seems to be impossible to uncheck it in registry. I tried:

32-bit:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy]
"EnableJavaUpdate"=dword:00000000
```

64-bit:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy]
"EnableJavaUpdate"=dword:00000000
"EnableAutoUpdateCheck"=dword:00000000
"NotifyDownload"=dword:00000001
"NotifyInstall"=dword:00000001
```

Problem is, that DWORD EnableJavaUpdate hide tab Update" on JavaControl Panel, but I don't want to hide this tab, **just unselect this checkbox**.

I tried to uncheck checkbox and visually compare content of registry path.

I also tried Sysinternals ProcMonitor, but can't find place in registry where this information is stored.

**EDIT**:

1.7.0_67 Java on x64 have problem, that EnableJavaUpdate in registry is set to 1 and it doesn't work (tab Update is not shown).
See [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUNrk.png).

1.7.0_51 Java on x64 have problem, that whole registry path is missing in computer. See [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQGGR.jpg).

1.7.0._51 Java on x86 have path in registry and also Update tab on Configure Java dialog. (I don't have screenshoot).

I need to stop asking for downloading new version and AFTER THAT solving update all Java old versions on all computers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my experience, disabling Java Update using the Java Control Panel doesn't work (it's not the UAC issue Oracle talks about) and neither does the associated registry values under the "Policy" key.  It's absurd, I know.

What does work is simply deleting the `SunJavaUpdateSched` value from the Windows "Run" key.  Of course, if you update or install Java later manually, this key will get recreated.  Since you mentioned having "many computers", here is an example of how to do it using the command line on Windows 7 64-bit:

`reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SunJavaUpdateSched" /f`

Answer (score 2):

Source [How To Disable Java Update Notifications on Windows 7 Network Computers](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/65555-how-to-disable-java-update-notifications-on-windows-7-network-computers)

> **Change Java Registry Keys**
>
> Open RegEdit on the Windows 7 PC. Before making any registry changes,
> it is recommended to first create a backup.
>
> To disable the Java Update Notifications browse to the following
> registry keys
>
> 32bit Users:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy
>
> - Change the EnableAutoUpdateCheck to 0
> - Change the EnableJavaUpdate to 0
>
> 64bit Users:
>
> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy
>
> - Change the EnableJavaUpdate to 0
> - Change the NotifyDownload to 0
> - Add a new DWORD called "EnableAutoUpdateCheck" and set to 0

The remainder of the article explains how to use a Windows Group Policy to disable Java Update notifications. You will need a Windows 7 computer with the latest Java installed and a Windows Server 2008 running your Group Policies.

Comment: it is more complicated, please see my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?
http://java.com/en/download/help/javacpl.xml

This seems to also re-enable the Java Plug-in check box under Advanced tab.
It is always grayed out otherwise, despite me being an admin on the box...

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Please edit your question to include the details of the steps found at the link you're referencing so that all may benefit from your answer, even if the linked site were ever to go down.

Answer (score 0):

I use this registry (`.reg`) file for this purpose:

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"SunJavaUpdateSched"=-
```